# every input other than integer gives 13 as a output why?

Tags: c

here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,sum=0;
    printf("enter any number to find its sum of digits");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while (num!=0) {
        sum+=num%10;
        num=num/10;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;

}
```

Input other than integer number always gives output 13 .
why this is so?

Comment: What value in `num` did you expect after `scanf("%d",&num)` when input was non-numeric?

Comment: i expected there will be an error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are failing to check the return value of `scanf()`.  Any value could come out.  You must always check your return values in C.

Comment: how to check return values ?

Comment: [sigh] Google scanf() to find out what it returns.